Before vm reboot I connected to a vm via ssh, but after I'm connecting to NSX Router
I think it's nat problem, but I've already configured it yesterday.I'm running a small lab under VMware cloud director.
134.17.15.XXX - public ip
NSX Edge nat output
++++++++++++++++ IPv4 rules/flows ++++++++++++++++
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 522 packets, 30229 bytes)
rid    pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
0       522 30229 int_dnat   all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
0       522 30229 usr_dnat   all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 446 packets, 24479 bytes)
rid    pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 16 packets, 2436 bytes)
rid    pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
0        16  2436 int_dnat   all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
0        16  2436 usr_dnat   all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 16 packets, 2436 bytes)
rid    pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
0        92  8186 int_snat   all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
0        92  8186 usr_snat   all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain int_dnat (2 references)
rid    pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain int_snat (1 references)
rid    pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
0         0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            policy match dir out pol ipsec mode tunnel

Chain usr_dnat (2 references)
rid    pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain usr_snat (1 references)
rid    pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
0        76  5750 LOG        all  --  *      vNic_0  192.168.100.0/24     0.0.0.0/0            LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "SNAT_"
0        76  5750 SNAT       all  --  *      vNic_0  192.168.100.0/24     0.0.0.0/0            to:134.17.15.XXX 

firewall config output
++++++++++++++++ IPv4 rules/flows ++++++++++++++++
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 3337 packets, 3168K bytes)
rid    pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
rid    pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
0       732 2763K ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
0       216  8676 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state INVALID
0      2210  382K block_in   all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
0       955  108K ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
0      1255  274K usr_rules  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
0         0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 181 packets, 13964 bytes)
rid    pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 2658 packets, 3118K bytes)
rid    pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
rid    pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
0       732 2763K ACCEPT     all  --  *      lo      0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
0         1   104 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state INVALID
0      2112  369K block_out  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
0         0     0 l2vpn_rules  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            PHYSDEV match --physdev-is-bridged
0      1266  183K ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
0       846  187K usr_rules  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
0         0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain block_in (1 references)
rid    pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain block_out (1 references)
rid    pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain l2vpn_rules (1 references)
rid    pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain usr_rules (2 references)
rid    pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
131080   758  180K ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            match-set 0_131080-os-v4-1 src
131079    90  6622 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            match-set 1_131079-os-v4-1 src LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "ACCEPT_131079"
131079    90  6622 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            match-set 1_131079-os-v4-1 src
131073  1253  274K ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

What I need to do for fix it? I tried to force ssh on VM (192.168.100.2) to work at 1367 port then telnet 134.17.15.XXX 1367 but it closed for some reason.
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused

Yes, that was DNAT Rule. I added
Chain usr_dnat (2 references)
rid    pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
0         1    52 LOG        tcp  --  vNic_0 *       0.0.0.0/0            134.17.15.XXX        multiport dports 22 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "DNAT_"
0         1    52 DNAT       tcp  --  vNic_0 *       0.0.0.0/0            134.17.15.XXX        multiport dports 22 to:192.168.100.2:22


